# PostGresql and PostGIS courses in Canada

Tags: postgis, postgresql, education, canada

I have been looking for good professional courses for learning more than just the basics for PostGresql nd PostGIS.  I have found a number of good courses, but they seem to all be in the US.  I was wondering if anyone knows of similar type courses being offered in Canada.

```
http://www.otg-nc.com/implementing-databases-postgresql/
http://www.otg-nc.com/postgresql-administration/
```

Thanks...

Comment: If career questions are okay then I guess this one's okay, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refractions Research offers s[elf-paced PostGIS training courses](http://refractions.net/company/news/20111111/). They also have other PostGIS training packages. You can check a sample outline [here](http://refractions.net/products/postgis/training/). They're based on British Columbia.

```
Refractions Research
Suite 419 – 1207 Douglas Street
Victoria, British Columbia
Canada, V8W-2E7
Phone: (250) 383-3022
```